# One command to npm install and bower in npm?

Tags: node.js, bower

A friend of mine said maven is king and npm and bower sucks because you have to run 2 commands. "npm install"... wait... then run "bower install". I heard node's package.json is able to support scripts. Is there a way for me to modify package.json so that I can do something like "npm setupmyproject" that will run both the npm install and bower install commands, then execute a grunt task? That way I can have one command to hit three birds?

Comment: Remember that just because a tool _can_ do everything doesn't mean it _should_ do everything. A shell script could easily take care of both use cases and then some (and it's not tied to a particular technology or tool).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you could add a single [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) to perform all those operations, e.g.

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "setup": "npm install && bower install && grunt build"
  }
}
```

Then you'll be able to run it with

```
npm run setup
```

Comment: An getting "missing script "setup""

Comment: @Rolando are you sure that you've added `"setup"` script to the `"scripts"` section of your `package.json` and saved all changes?